# Why is User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false when called via CORS

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, asp.net-core-2.0, fetch-api

Why is User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false when called via CORS, but true when called via same domain?

I have a working asp.net core 2 cookieauth app that is CORS enabled.

When I call;

> api/Identity/establish-session

an AUTHCOOKIE gets dropped in both
CORS and local ajax calls.
Conversely when I call

> api/Identity/sign-out

The AUTHCOOKIE gets removed.  All good so far.

After a successful establish-session, when I call the following;

> api/Identity/check-authentication

User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false when called via CORS, but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true when called from the same domain.
I don't know if this is because of how I call it in javascript or if I have something configured wrong on the asp.net app.  I thought I just had to have credentials: 'include' set in my fetch call?

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Identity")]
public class IdentityController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("establish-session")]
    public async Task EstablishAuthenticatedSession(string username, string password)
    {

        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
        };

        var claims = new[] {new Claim("name", username), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")};
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await
            HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                properties);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("sign-out")]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("check-authentication")]
    public async Task<bool> CheckAuthentication()
    {
        return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Here is my javascript snippets;

```
establishAuthenticatedSession(){

            let self = this;
            var model = this.get();
            console.log(model);
            var url = "https://localhost:44310/api/Identity/establish-session?username=herb&password=1234";
            fetch(url,
            {
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
                method: 'POST'
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                self.set({ establishSession:{ message:"Success" }});
            }).catch(function(error) {
                self.set({ establishSession:{ message:error.message }});
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            });

        },
        signOut(){

            let self = this;
            var model = this.get();
            console.log(model);
            var url = "https://localhost:44310/api/Identity/sign-out";
            fetch(url,
            {
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                self.set({ signoutResult:{ message:"Success" }});
            }).catch(function(error) {
                self.set({ signoutResult:{ message:error.message }});
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            });

        },
        checkAuthenticatedSession(){
            let self = this;
            var model = this.get();
            console.log(model);
            var url = "https://localhost:44310/api/Identity/check-authentication";
            fetch(url,
            {
                credentials: 'include',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
            })
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                self.set({ checkAuthenticatedSession:{ message:res }});
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                self.set({ checkAuthenticatedSession:{ message:error.message }});
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            });
        }
```

This is my CORS setup;

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

Comment: So I think I know the why, which is that my AUTHCOOKIE isn't getting sent even though credentials:include.  I can reproduce this as well with https://test-cors.org/.  So it looks like it is how the cookie is made may be the reason.  Is there anything special that is needed for CORS created cookies to be sent back by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the cookie needs to be set as SameSiteMode.None.  The hint I got was that that ARRAfinity cookie from azure as set to non and it was being sent where mine was not.

In my app  I had to set it as follows;

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...           

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn"; ;
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/login");
                    options.Cookie.Name = "AUTHCOOKIE";
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
                    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

                }
            );
        ...
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
        };

        app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);
        ...
    }
}
```